# Does NSFetchRequest setPropertiesToGroupBy: return all entities that match?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, macos, core-data

I'm developing an app for iOS, and I can't find much documentation on the new `NSFetchRequest setPropertiesToGroupBy:` method.

I have a bunch of entity A objects that have relationships with multiple entity B objects.

I want to fetch all entity B objects that match a specific pattern and group them by entity A. This is so that I don't have a separate DB fetch for every entity A. The results would ideally be structured so that I could iterate over groups of equal entity As, and then would have all the entity Bs matching the pattern from one fetch request.

I can see that the `setPropertiesToGroupBy:` method should let me group by the inverse B->A relationship, and returns an array of `NSDictionaries`. But does that mean each item in the `NSArray` corresponds to one group by entity A? And that the corresponding `NSManagedObject` subclasses can be found somewhere in the `NSDictionary`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it doesn't. There are two ways to do this:

- Use multiple requests
- Have one request to get all A entities where the inverse A->B relationship is in a group of Bs. Then include an `NSSortDescriptor` to sort by B and separate the results in to groups.

The latter is probably quicker because an in-memory split avoids repeated DB accesses and fetch request parsing.